# How to search/filter for ONLY empty fields in the admin panel?

Tags: database, search, admin-panel

I'm looking for orders that specifically did **not** use a coupon code, and therefore have no visible value in the "coupon" field.

Which value do I search for?

I tried "NULL", ""(as in, two quotation marks with nothing in them), leaving the field empty and just a space character. None of those worked, unfortunately.

Don't have full admin access, only our orders, so I can't make any changes to the actual search setting itself.

P.S.: Hope this post is adequate, first time posting on any stackexchange. Thanks in advance for any and all hints!

Quick edit: I have a workaround of sorting by coupons, but that does not allow me to sort by a more relevant value (date), as specific times are affected, and therefore seems unviable for my needs.

Comment: it is not feasible to filter with empty fields, but you can try sorting with coupon field (if sortable ) it may show all empty rows first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm aware of this workaround (added it to my original post), but it is inadequate for my needs, as it disallows me to sort by date, which is necessary for my case.

Would it be possible to search for the value "false" maybe and get the necessary results?